# HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error caused by isapi com component

Tags: iis, com, iis-7

I have IIS7 and am trying to get a website working for development reasons (not production).
So far, I'm getting

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
```

and so I can't get off square 1.

Comment: with that much detail about what you're doing, what code have, what errors you have in your logs, you'll likely stay at square 0. (square 1 would at least have a `<blink>` tag working :-) )

Comment: When I browse to http://localhost/, I get: Module IsapiModule, Notification ExecuteRequestHandler, Handler AboMapperCustom-36753, Error Code 0x80070003, Requested URL http://localhost:80/, Physical Path c:\My Dropbox, Logon Method Anonymous, Logon User Anonymous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a COM error.  The most common error is that you need to register the COM service on the server (the COM you will need to register is AboMapperCustom).

You register a COM using the regsvr32 utility.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the event log to see what's the 500 error about.

Comment: #Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2011-04-17 00:58:13
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2011-04-17 00:58:13 ::1 GET / - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows;+U;+Windows+NT+6.0;+en-US;+rv:1.9.2.16)+Gecko/20110319+Firefox/3.6.16+(+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET4.0E) 500 0 3 3
2011-04-17 00:58:15 ::1 GET / - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows;+U;+Windows+NT+6.0;+en-US;+rv:1.9.2.16)+Gecko/20110319+Firefox/3.6.16+(+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET4.0E) 500 0 3 1